# How can Android Studio debug a framework on Android U?

Tags: android, android-studio

I was using android studio before to debug android framework code, on Android 13 (T) I can get to the debugging process by attach to process, but on Android 14 (U) no processes are listed, I first thought it was the JDK, then I replaced it with OPEN JDK 17, still nothing, then I updated Android Studio to the latest version, still no processes listed. Now when I connect my phone to Android T, it doesn't show the processes either, just a small popup box.

I've upgraded my JDK and software version and still can't debug properly, I even went so far as to download an ubuntu VM specifically to install Android Studio For Platform, but the result is still the same! now I want to be able to debug my system properly.

Comment: What OS do you use? What is the content of the "small popup box"?

Comment: I'm using window 10, and an ubuntu virtual machine, and the box prompts something like “No processes to attach to.”